# Google Maps Does not Zoom "organically" when new markers are loaded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code that loads XML graphic markers, and I also set it to zoom when new markers are loaded. What I don't like however, is that the zoom happens "instantly" and doesnt zoom to level slowly, and also, for some reason the map zooms out much further than it needs too. I would like the map to zoom out only as far as it needs to so that the markers are in view.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
clearOverlays();
downloadUrl("AllActivityxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
markerBounds.extend(point);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow

          });

          markersArray.push(marker);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          map.fitBounds(markerBounds);



        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*zoom happens "instantly" and doesnt zoom to level slowly* -- that is how it actually happens when you do `fitBounds()`. Looks like you want something like the `map.panTo()` which makes the transition on map slowly unlike the `map.setCenter()`, but that is not the case in fitBounds().

*map zooms out much further than it needs too --* move the `map.fitBounds(markerBounds);` outside the `for loop`

Comment: Hey thanks, but putting `map.panTo(markerBounds)` right outside the loop does nothing. There is no error, however there is no zoom either.

Comment: NO. map.panTo() will not work with a bounds variable and that is what I mentioned. Your first issue about zooming slowly has no workaround. Did I solve your second issue on zooming?

Comment: Hi Cdeez, not really - because I wanted the zoom to feel natural. However after searching through google I found out that this is not possible. Thanks for your answer however.